# How to change file name while downloading from wget?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I try to download file so `wget -P /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/movies/2019/ https://example.com/video.mp4`

After download, the name of this file will be `video.mp4` and can I change the name directly on download? to set it for example  `love.mp4`?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only. Please ask on [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. Though if you're talking about doing it programmatically, please [edit] to clarify the process.

Comment: have you read the manual of wget?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use -O or --output-document=FILE

Example:

```
wget -P /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/movies/2019/ -O love.mp4 https://example.com/video.mp4
```

Comment: But it locates the file in root and not in /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/movies/2019/

Comment: Remove -P and specify the path before love.mp4, I edit the answer if it work @Aiooo